# Error in Servlet part of  Android Documentation for  Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)

Tags: android, servlets, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement new helpers for `Google Cloud to Messaging`. The Android documentation for Server side implementation [here](http://pages.citebite.com/g2a6c7p9quml) is

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;

Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder(regId).build();
Result result = sender.send(message, 5);
```

But when I copied the code in the a Java Servlet is showing an error in 3rd and 4th line.

Comment: Paste the error message.

Comment: The Editor does not recognize line no 3 and 4 in the above code.

Comment: myApiKey and regid should be something.

Comment: @Akki Yes. I replaced them with appropriate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given in Android documentation has errors.

Full code for the server side of `GCM` is in `Android -> android-sdk ->extras -> google -> gcm -> gcm-server`.

Comment: I have the same problem! My problem is at Sender sender = new Sender(ApiKey);

The path you gave is for the source code of gcm-server.jar. Should i use the source code instead the .jar?

Comment: @RenanMobile Open a new question with all the details.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the problem was solved at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355446/gcm-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gcm-server-sender

Answer (score 2):

you see this link

> https://github.com/ketanpatel25/GCM-Demo

GCM Folder in GCM-Demo / gcm / samples / gcm-demo-server

Server said all Demo code given you try

Answer (score 0):

did you fix this problem?

If your editor doesn't recognise Sender and Message then it can't find gcm-server.jar

Copy the gcm-server.jar file from the SDK's gcm-server/dist directory to your server classpath